# Tilemaps and colour overlays

Tags: android, tilemap, isometric

I am currently developing an isometric tile game for android. I am currently working on how I  to handle rendering the tiles in an efficient way. So I was wondering about the possibility of using a small set of grey-scale tile images with different coloured overlays, rather than many coloured tile images.

[image: Isometric Map]

Has this been done before? Is it do-able in android? How would it affect efficiency?

Comment: What game engine are you using?

Comment: I've been **trying** to use AndEngine for the past week and getting pretty frustrated with it. I have finally been able to show a black screen but nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you want to use to render the games, but in general, that is possible. In Monogame for example it is just changing the "Color.White" to the color you want (e. g. Color.Green)
What you are trying to archive in the image above won't be possible using a pure tile-based approach: Some tiles on the border between the green and the original are split. I guess you have to make a zig-zag border so it doesn't go through tiles, but only through the spaces between those tiles. The water (I guess it's water in the top corner?) would also be rendered on it's own, because the behavior is quite confusing: when viewed in the original, it is gray (which is logic), but then, it turns blue on the green overlay. So you have to implement the water differently from the tile system (or at least store the color of the water somewhere, most of the rendering code can be shared for sure)

Comment: Yes, that split was a mistake on my part. I've been researching this for the past week best resource I've found on this so far is [this tutorial](http://www.yarrcade.com/2010/09/19/terrain-modificatio-in-grid-based-games-part-1-isometric-landscape/). I've begun some code and will post my solution on here once it is finished.